# Example of two different smooth structure on a manifold.

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ a manifold. Two atlas $A_1=\{(U_i,\varphi_i)\}$ and $A_2=\{(V_i,\psi_i)\}$. They define the same smooth structure if whenever $f$ is smooth wrt $A_1$ then it will be smooth wrt $A_2$. For example $$A_1=\{(\mathbb R^n,id_{\mathbb R^n})\}$$
and $$A_2=\{(B_1(x),Id_{B_1(x)})\mid x\in \mathbb R^n\}$$
are two different atlas but they define the same smooth structure.

Do you have an example (on $\mathbb R^n$ or any easy smooth manifold) that describe two different smooth structure ? I don't really see it.

Comment: If you google “different smooth structures” you get a few links to expository papers.  This slideshow might be useful: http://users.jyu.fi/~eejohaka/talk/exotic_structures.pdf

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: In your document, it's written (page 6) that $M=\mathbb R$ with the chart $\varphi:M\to \mathbb R$ defined by $\varphi(x)=Sgn(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ is smooth. How can it be true since even $\varphi$ is not smooth ? (not derivable at $0$).

Comment: $\phi$ only needs to be a homeomorphism to be a chart.  Any pair of charts $\phi$ and $\psi$ must satisfy the condition that $\phi\circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth.  Since there is only one chart, that condition is automatically satisfied.  When you say $\phi$ isn't smooth, you're comparing it to the usual atlas on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So in fact every homeomorphism $\varphi: M\to \mathbb R^n$ is a smooth structure, right ? @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two different smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}$ : $\{(\mathbb{R},\operatorname{id})\}$ and $\{(\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x^3)\}$.

Using the same idea, you can prove that there exists an uncountable set of smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

If $M$ is a topological manifold, its homeomorphisms group acts on its set of smooth structures by:
$$f\cdot\{(U_i,\varphi_i)\}_{i\in I}=\{f^{-1}(U_i),\varphi_i\circ f\}_{i\in I},$$
and generally an orbit of a given smooth atlas is uncountable.

Comment: But do you agree that there are the same topological manifold ? (not as smooth manifold but as topological)

Comment: Yes, there are!